# Can Zap be used as a DAST tool via API without spidering?

Tags: zap

I'm trying to use Zap as a DAST tool via the API and it's getting a bit annoying.

Can i use the tool as an attack tool instead of a proxy tool? what i mean is, currently i can't launch an active scan without the url being in the tree, which is only done via the spider afaik right?

What i want is to provide the url and launch an active scan based on a policy and get results, now that i think about it, this is similar to fuzzing just with attack vectors, although i see the logic of what to do with URL X if there is no history or scanning done, can't it just scan the page for actions and variables? the main difference is page\url scanning contrary to spidering which assumes there are other urls.

After writing this i'm not sure it can be done without a spider unless you're in my situation so let me explain it.
Lets say for example's sake i just want to scan the login page for SQLI and i'm using Owasp JuiceShop to make things easier, can i tell zap to attack the one page? the only way i found on that example is via the POST method since the url is not a static page and isn't being pick up by Zap unless it's an action, but then i can't launch it without spidering so this is like a loop.

Sorry for the long post hopefully you can provide some insights.

Update in comments

Comment: I think i see the problem now, if it's a POST only request then both spiders don't take that option into account, they just spider with GET instead.
so the only place a POST request can come to the scan tree is from a user action which beats the purpose of this question and situation
although this may seem be a spider issue since you can't provide the method to be used i really think it's a scan tree issue, if you would have added the ability to manually add url's to the scan tree then the active scanner would do the job which is what i need here.

Comment: Just found another problem, if i run Zap with GUI and tell it to active scan the user login of Juice Shop then it does find an SQLI but if i clear the history and repeat the same request or do manual ones of my own even with the DB error it still doesn't find an issue for SQLI. I'm really puzzled as i run the same request it sends itself which it identifies as SQLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZAP has to know about the site its going to attack. We deliberately separate the concepts of discovery and attacking because theres no one discovery option thats best for all. You can use the standard spider, the ajax spider, import urls, import defns like OpenAPI, proxy your browser, proxy regression tests or even make direct requests to the target site via the ZAP API.

It looks like you have quite a few questions about ZAP. The ZAP User Group is probably a better forum for them: https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users

Comment: Thanks i've moved it to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zaproxy-users/BxmfBwOb7h0